# how to add buttons at the bottom of the screen and edit text as the third column of the page?

Tags: java, android, button, android-layout, android-edittext

i want to create a page ,in such a way that a list should come in which first two columns,shows product name and its cost,and the third column should be an edit text to fill quantity.moreover i need three buttons at the bottom of the page.i am a newbie t android programming,plz help

Comment: please provide more information that what actually you want.. if possible then please put an image of layout that help me to understand which kind of layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RelativeLayout that contains 2 layouts:

1. [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for the first requirement.
2. Another RelativeLayout for keeping buttons at the bottom:

For 3 buttons u set the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.
For the 1st button u give `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`
and the 2nd button and 3rd buttons u give `android:toRightOf=""` property.

Comment: thanks,will let u know if any problem occurs,keep visitng this link

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use custom Listiview for this pupose. Your mainview will contain a listview and the 3 buttons at the bottoms as you want. 
Checkout following example for custom listview

[Custom Listview](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)